# Partially Transparent/ Low Opacity Navigation Bar?

Tags: html, css

I have looked at a few tutorials, youtube videos and source codes of websites that implement this design, but I cant get it done. 
Heres a image of the type of navigation bar I would like to create.
http://imgur.com/BHavGXg

Here is my html of navigation bar:

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Notes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Classes</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Works</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Research</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
```

Here is my CSS for navigation bar:

```
    .nav {
       width: 100%;
       border: 1px solid #ccc;
       color: #fff;
       border-right: none;
       background-color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.6);
       color: rgba(1, 1, 1, 0.8);
}
```

Thanks for any help. Its greatly appreciated from a beginner like myself.

Comment: check whether any other class overriding your background property.

Comment: Mate, what is the question here? I would help or I think everyone would, but it's not clear what is preventing you from doing this? Do you want someone to write the whole thing for you?

Comment: No, I just need some hints as to what might the problem be.....

Comment: I see nothing wrong with what you did. I assume you set the `li` elements to display as inline-blocks. As an example: http://jsfiddle.net/oqyx6gkr/1/

Answer (score 1):

You would have to create a different class for both the nav and the text. For the navigator to be transparent you would use the property

```
opacity: (Insert value);
```

Hope this helps!